# Is there flag to specify memory limit for kubernetes pods using kubectl run?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to create a pod and pass in memory limit without creating a yaml file. Or is there a way to modify the memory limit on a pod which is already running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really think of a way of how to enforce a limit of memory from `kubectl run` but it can be enforced by applying the resource below.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: mem-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      memory: 512Mi
    defaultRequest:
      memory: 256Mi
    type: Container
```